# Regex to put missing quotes around keys of arrays

Tags: php, regex

I try to correct my PHP-code and add to the quotes `'` around the keys of the arrays in my source-code.

I have like 10,000 files to correct. Can I use some regular expressions to achieve that?

I tried to use this regular expression, but it is not perfect:

```
\$([0-9a-zA-z_\-]+)\[([0-9a-zA-z_\-]+)\]\[([0-9a-zA-z_\-]+)\]
```

to

```
\$$1['$2']['$3']
```

Example of what I want to change:

```
$_SESSION[Name][name_2] to $_SESSION['Name']['name_2']
$_POST[Name][na-me_2] to $_SESSION['Name']['na-me_2']
$_GET[Name][na-me_2] to $_GET['Name']['na-me_2']
$tab[name_one] to $tab['name_one']
```

Comment: what if you have some keys already quoted? or use `[]` in other ways?

Comment: Just wanted to point out that if you have any array values being used in string interpolation, (`$example = "text $array[key] moretext";`) those keys should not be quoted, so whatever you end up using should take that into account.

Answer (score 2):

We can most likely capture our indices with a group, then `preg_replace` it, maybe with an expression similar to:

```
\[(.+?)\]
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/\[(.+?)\]/m';
$str = '$_SESSION[Name][name_2]
$_POST[Name][na-me_2]
$_GET[Name][na-me_2]
$tab[name_one]';
$subst = '[\'$1\']';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified/changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Aa4u60/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

If we wish to have more constraints, we can surely update this expression. For example, if we would have already had keys with `'` or `"`, then we can just add a new boundary such as all chars except `'` and `"` in a char class:

```
[^'"]*
```

and our expression would become:

```
\[([^'"]*?)\]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Er8ahJ/1/)

#### Test

```
$re = '/\[([^\'"]*?)\]/m';
$str = '$_SESSION[Name][name_2]
$_POST[Name][na-me_2]
$_GET[\'Name\'][na-me_2]
$tab[name_one]
$_POST[Name]["na-me_2"]
$_POST[\'Name\']["na-me_2"]';
$subst = '[\'$1\']';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
$_SESSION['Name']['name_2']
$_POST['Name']['na-me_2']
$_GET['Name']['na-me_2']
$tab['name_one']
$_POST['Name']["na-me_2"]
$_POST['Name']["na-me_2"]
```

Comment: I am wondering what with two example $_POST[Name]['na-me_2']  and  $_POST[Name]["na-me_2"] i don't whant to change [] that have " or ' inside